# Wordpress Bones Theme CSS and JS Versioning

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website that has been built using the bones wordpress theme. No matter what I do I can't seem to get versioning to work on css and js using the wordpress enqueue functions.

Is there something in bones, maybe a filter that I can't find that is stripping the versioning out?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably lucky that it's not there by default, most people try and remove it as it defaults to Wordpress version number (why?).

I found the best way to add it is to add the my_wp_default_styles function to your functions.php. Also a neat trick is to check the last modified date of the main css file and make that the version timestamp.

```
function my_wp_default_styles($styles) {
  $styles->default_version = filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/style.css');
}
add_action("wp_default_styles", "my_wp_default_styles");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it !

There's a filter into Bones theme, which remove every CSS/JS versionning.

Just look into the `bones-theme/library/bones.php` file, you got a filter function

```
// ~L.48
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'bones_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );

/** Some code **/
// ~L.89
function bones_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
  if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
  return $src;
}
```

You can either edit it or just remove the hook, and place your versionning inside wp_enqueue_script()/wp_enqueue_style() functions.